# what should I do with "You don't have permission to access" error?

Tags: react-native, fetch

on a React-Native project I'm trying to fetch some data from an API but I end up with this error:

> "error":"You don't have permission to access!"

here is my code:

```
import React, {useEffect} from 'react';
import {View, Text} from 'react-native';
import base64 from 'react-native-base64';
const ProductScreen = props => {
    const url = 'Some_URL';
    const encoded = base64.encode('user:pass');
    const auth = 'Basic ' + encoded;

    useEffect( () => {
        fetch(url, {
          method: 'POST',
          'Authorization': auth,
        }).then(response => response.json()).then(responseJson => {
            const jsonString = JSON.stringify(responseJson);
            console.log(jsonString);
        });



    }

    );

  return (
    <View>
      <Text>some text</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

export default ProductScreen;
```

what does this error mean? are my username and password wrong? or it means I need to get permission from the user of the app for fetching? or something else?

Answer (score 0):

the problem was the 'https'. By changing it to 'http' the problem was solved.

Comment: This may have unblocked you, but please do not consider changing from HTTPS to HTTP a solution you can put into production.  Your error sounds like a generic Auth error that you can work through by consulting the documentation for the API you're calling.  What you've done by switching to HTTP is fine for testing purposes, but putting it into production will put your users at risk.